# why did he say this? or why has he said this?

Tags: grammar

While you were watching a movie, you heard a dialogue and wondered why the actor said, X instead of Y.
now if you want to ask your grammatically question from your friend on a chat with a screenshot from that specific scene, which should be used?
1-why did he say this?
2-why has he said this?

Comment: [grammatically correct question] This question is asked over and over again. The answer depends on you. You might want to search on this site for Present Perfect and Simple Past in the search box.

Comment: I would pick `Why did he say this?`. You refer to a specific action in the movie when the actor said it. This action is also not related to the present.